# Histogram in log scale with Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Hello I have this code :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import numpy as np

a = np.array([2.79e-06,2.47e-06,0.000122,3.9e-05,0.000527,9.41e-06,3.11e-05,4.63e-05,0.000749,0.000499,0.000174,0.000984,0.000912,5.86e-05,0.000344,0.000754,0.000267,2.53e-06,8.73e-05,0.000791,1.69e-06,7.56e-05,0.001,3.1e-06,0.000305,2.4e-06,6.37e-06,3.25e-07,6.67e-05,0.000167,0.000954,2.36e-07,3.8e-06,0.000337,8.1e-06,1.68e-05,0.000332,3.64e-06,2e-05,5.97e-06,0.000808,2.34e-06,0.000121,0.000972,2.59e-05,0.000761,8.76e-05,0.000253,0.000819,7.88e-06,5.04e-05,1.75e-05,5.83e-05,0.000271,3.18e-06,3.29e-05,0.000979,0.000925,2.55e-05,0.000347,0.000269,9.51e-06,5.54e-06,7.18e-05,1.44e-05,8.42e-09,1.86e-05,0.000377,1.68e-05,0.000991,4.69e-06,9.87e-05,4.45e-05,4.05e-06,6.76e-05,5.66e-06,6.51e-06,3.76e-06,6.44e-05,2.91e-09,0.000565,9.18e-06,0.0003,0.0002,9.43e-05,8.57e-06,6.32e-05,4e-06,5.18e-06,0.000181,0.000999,1.67e-05,0.000941,6.49e-05,0.000141,4.07e-06,2.68e-06,0.000407,1.47e-05,5.2e-06,6.53e-06,0.000462,1.38e-05,0.000794,3.32e-07,2.19e-06,0.000432,0.000156])


plt.clf()
plt.hist(a)
plt.xscale('log')
plt.title('Histogram of a')
plt.savefig('a.png')
```

But I don't understand when I see the histogram I get this picture :

[image]

But it is not good because the length of the different bins are not equals !

Could you help me please ?

Thank you so much !

Edit :

This is the new code for Florian :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import numpy as np

a = np.array([2.79e-06,2.47e-06,0.000122,3.9e-05,0.000527,9.41e-06,3.11e-05,4.63e-05,0.000749,0.000499,0.000174,0.000984,0.000912,5.86e-05,0.000344,0.000754,0.000267,2.53e-06,8.73e-05,0.000791,1.69e-06,7.56e-05,0.001,3.1e-06,0.000305,2.4e-06,6.37e-06,3.25e-07,6.67e-05,0.000167,0.000954,2.36e-07,3.8e-06,0.000337,8.1e-06,1.68e-05,0.000332,3.64e-06,2e-05,5.97e-06,0.000808,2.34e-06,0.000121,0.000972,2.59e-05,0.000761,8.76e-05,0.000253,0.000819,7.88e-06,5.04e-05,1.75e-05,5.83e-05,0.000271,3.18e-06,3.29e-05,0.000979,0.000925,2.55e-05,0.000347,0.000269,9.51e-06,5.54e-06,7.18e-05,1.44e-05,8.42e-09,1.86e-05,0.000377,1.68e-05,0.000991,4.69e-06,9.87e-05,4.45e-05,4.05e-06,6.76e-05,5.66e-06,6.51e-06,3.76e-06,6.44e-05,2.91e-09,0.000565,9.18e-06,0.0003,0.0002,9.43e-05,8.57e-06,6.32e-05,4e-06,5.18e-06,0.000181,0.000999,1.67e-05,0.000941,6.49e-05,0.000141,4.07e-06,2.68e-06,0.000407,1.47e-05,5.2e-06,6.53e-06,0.000462,1.38e-05,0.000794,3.32e-07,2.19e-06,0.000432,0.000156])


plt.clf()
plt.hist(a, bins=np.logspace(a.min(), a.max(), 50))
plt.xscale('log')
plt.title('Histogram of a')
plt.savefig('a.png')
```

And this is what I get :

[Histogram of a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/on2Tq.png)

Comment: So, you just want to change the x scale labels to a scientific notation?

Comment: I want to have the same size for the bins !

Comment: You can accomplish this by removing the log scale. The only difference will be the x scale format since the y scale remains linear

Comment: I know that but in this case I lose the log scale and if you look at my data I need log scale because I have a lot of little quantities close to 0...

Comment: I think I figured it out. Try `np.logspace(np.log10(a.min()), np.log10(a.max())
, 50)`

Comment: The issue I think is that your `np.logspace` has `np.inf` values in most cases. Hence you don't see anything but a line.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a logarithmic scale, that's why some bins seem larger. But they are actually all the same size if you remove `plt.xscale('log')` from your code.

If you need to keep the logarithm scale, then, create your own customised scale for the bins.
Look at the documentation here
https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html

Florian

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand why it is like this ! Is there a way to have bins with the same size ?

Comment: Your bins are the same size. What you see is just due to your logarithm scale. Remove `plt.xscale('log')` and you will see that it is the same size.

Comment: Yeah obviously but I want to have the results in the log scale with the same size for the bins...

Comment: If you want to keep your logarithm scale, then use another scale for the bins, like :
`plt.hist(a, bins=np.logspace(0.1, 1.0, 50))`

Comment: If I remove I lose the log scale

Comment: Ok, you have to do it according to your dataset, sorry.

Try with :
`plt.hist(a, bins=np.logspace(a.min(), a.max(), 50))`

Comment: It is always the same I get a line... :/

Comment: I put inside my question in the Edit